# Jquery .each not working, bad code or a better method available?

Tags: jquery

First the setup:
jquery 1.5.1
Firefox 4.0

Goal:
I've got a bunch of textboxes that are enabled/disabled using checkboxes.  If a textbox is enabled, I want it to have a value greater than zero.

HTML for one of the boxes(there are a variable number of them on the page):

```
<input type="text" value="0" name="RequestList[4].iCount" id="RequestList_4__iCount" class="num-box">
```

My jQuery using .each that doesn't work:

```
var oneFill = false;
$('.num-box').each(function() {
    var myItem = $(this);
    if (myItem.attr('disabled') == false) {
        if (myItem.val() > 0) {
            oneFill = true;
        }
    }
});
if (!oneFill) {
```

When I trace the above code in Firebug, it doesn't do anything.  It continues to the next line of code(if(!oneFill)).

When I use $('.num-box') in Firebug, it returns a complete list of all textboxes.  So I'm very confident that I've got the right selector.

So the question is, what did I do wrong?  I've looked at a host of examples here and it appears my use of .each was correct.

But, is there a more efficient method for checking all enabled textboxes with class of num-box?

**Addition1**
@artlung
Using continuing my sample html above, I would have at least the following:

```
<input type="text" value="0" name="RequestList[1].iCount" id="RequestList_1__iCount" class="num-box">
<input type="text" value="0" name="RequestList[2].iCount" id="RequestList_2__iCount" class="num-box">
<input type="text" value="0" name="RequestList[3].iCount" id="RequestList_3__iCount" class="num-box">
<input type="text" value="0" name="RequestList[4].iCount" id="RequestList_4__iCount" class="num-box">
```

The checkboxes would look like:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="RDEquipListItem[1]" id="RDEquipListItem_1_">
<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="RDEquipListItem[2]" id="RDEquipListItem_2_">
<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="RDEquipListItem[3]" id="RDEquipListItem_3_">
<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="RDEquipListItem[4]" id="RDEquipListItem_4_">
```

I've got java script that enables/disables the textboxes when the appropriate checkbox is checked.

So far, I've seen some good adjustments to the meat of my code.  I will vote for those tomorrow.

My confusion is whether there is an issue with my .each portion:

```
$('.num-box').each(function() {
```

**Addition2**
I've been playing with some of the results.  My current code looks like:

```
var oneFill = false;
var myEnabled = $('.num-box:enabled');
myEnabled.each(function() {
    var myItem = $(this);
    if (parseInt(myItem.val()) > 0) {
        oneFill = true;
    }
});
if (!oneFill) {
```

myEnabled gets the correct list of elements that are enabled.  *thumbs up*

However, the myEnabled.each does nothing.

Is there an issue with a single item being used by .each?

**Final comment**
Not sure why this was giving me an issue but I had to reorder the logic a bit.  Even using Firebug, it wouldn't step into the ".each" code but the results are correct.

Final code(NOTE: .num-box are textboxes that are enabled/disabled by checkboxes):

```
//make sure one item has been filled in and all are greater than zero
var allFilled = true;
var myEnabled = $('.num-box:enabled');
//check that we have at least one item checked out
if (myEnabled.length == 0) {
    alert("At least one needs to be filled.");
    return false;
}

$.each(myEnabled, function() {
    var myItem = $(this);
    if (parseInt(myItem.val()) <= 0) {
        allFilled = false;
    }
});
if (!allFilled)
{
    //go do something
```

Comment: It's working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/CzNMJ/

Comment: Check what `myItem.attr('disabled')` and `myItem.val()` outputs as well.

Comment: One thing, if you're checking for values greater than 0, you want to parse the value as a number. So you want: `(parseInt(myItem.val(), 10) > 0)` for that portion.

Comment: Care to share more of the html - several checkboxes and textboxes, not just one textbox?

Comment: @artlung, more html showing.  The example shows 4 checkboxes and 4 textboxes... but there can be any number of them.

Comment: @MoarCodePlz, the generic selector I've chosen works ($('.num-box')) but for some reason when I do a step thru in Firebug, the .each line is skipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var oneFill = false;
$('.num-box').each(function() {
    var myItem = $(this);
    if (myItem.is(":enabled") && parseInt(myItem.val()) > 0) {
            oneFill = true;

    }
});
if (!oneFill) {
}
```

Comment: This helped clean up my code so I ended up with the code in Addition 2.  I decided to combine the enabled into the selector.  Any idea on why .each will not work?

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to check whether or not the current `num-box` is disabled by doing the following...

```
myItem.is(':disabled')
```

**EDIT**

could you accomplish what you want to do without using the .each?

something like... http://jsfiddle.net/fWCxj/2/

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="RDEquipListItem[2]" id="RDEquipListItem_2_">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="text" value="0" name="RequestList[2].iCount" id="RequestList_2__iCount" class="num-box" disabled="disabled">
<br />

<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="RDEquipListItem[3]" id="RDEquipListItem_3_">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="text" value="0" name="RequestList[3].iCount" id="RequestList_3__iCount" class="num-box" disabled="disabled">
<br />

<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="RDEquipListItem[4]" id="RDEquipListItem_4_">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="text" value="0" name="RequestList[4].iCount" id="RequestList_4__iCount" class="num-box" disabled="disabled">
<br />
```

**JS**

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    var cb = $(this);
    cb.next('input[type=text]').prop('disabled', cb.is(':not(:checked)'));
});

var oneFill = $('.num-box:not(:disabled)').length > 0;
alert(oneFill);
```

Comment: This helped clean up my code so I ended up with the code in Addition 2.  Any idea on why .each will not work?

Comment: I've updated a solution above which doesn't answer your question regarding .each but may work for what you are trying to do, at least what I think you are trying to do =) let me know if I'm misunderstanding...

Comment: The check is being performed as part of my validation before sending the data to the server.

Answer (score 1):

`.attr()` returns a string, not a boolean character. if you want to check to see if an input is disabled or not, use `.is(':disabled')`